# Who controls a PC's companions?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

During the first session, one player created a PC that has 2 companions. Do the rules say whether the GM or the player controls these companions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They are typically ST controlled.**

First off, there's not an explicit definition of "companion." In general, satellite characters serve three purposes: mechanical, story seeds, and flavor.

In the Merits section of the core book, there are several types of satellite characters listed: Allies, Contacts, Mentor, Retainer, and Staff, among others (some creatures, eg, Vampires, also have Touchstones). Each of those has a mechanical benefit; a "guy my guy knows" who does not fall into one of those categories thus should not provide a consistent benefit - in other words, one's stoner roommate is not able to "show up piloting a helicopter" to get your troupe out of a burning warehouse unless he is at least a 3 dot Retainer or Ally.

Mechanically beneficial satellites are rolled for (and controlled) by the ST. For example, in the text for Mentor (CoD p 51.): "Alternately, *you may ask the Storyteller* to have the mentor act on your character's behalf..."

Another purpose is story seeds: your cousin who's always running away from home - last time, she came back covered in blood. Or your troupe is at an impasse for getting into the docks, until it turns out an old coworker started working there last week. Note that many times, some of the beneficial characters may also work as story seeds - for example, Status in a criminal gang [which may be mostly interacting with a friendly gang member or two] may mean the leader calls upon the character to find a missing lieutenant, for example.

Some troupes find it helpful for players to suggest possible plot hooks and story seeds for satellite characters they created, but it's still up to the ST to decide which seeds get grown into full threads. In other troupes, they are purely under the control of the ST from their inception.

Lastly, they may be background flavor. For example, if a character has some sort of fame, or is particularly memorable for ordinary people, the barista that always recognizes her and starts making her usual without prompting may deserve some acknowledgement. This can fall within player control, but there is a danger of players thusly undermining the mood the ST is trying to set up. For example, say this character is suffering from a curse that causes social poisoning - describing the hostiles glares she is getting as people deliberately shove her out of their way is completely undermined if the barista greets her with a smile (rather than a sneer.)

Essentially, if the satellite character has dice - has a mechanical benefit - then they are bought with Merit dots as above. The ST explicitly controls their dice, and thus, controls them.

If they offer no benefit, but may be a liability, or are intended as story seed generators, since this is the role of the ST, their control should typically fall under the ST's duties.

If they offer no benefit or liability, there shouldn't be major drawbacks to having the player control them, but again, the ST should have a better idea of how they "fit in" and, most often, should be responsible for them.

Comment: Thanks for the long reply. I've started the player chronicle with her character driving on desolated route with her friends, listening to music. I've tried to eliminate the friends but I've sidetracked on the story, so for now they remain in the game.

Comment: Appreciated. I've kept my answer as neutrally toned as possible, since I wasn't sure you are the ST, but since you are - enjoy the ancillary characters, safe in the knowledge that they are "red shirts" to used (read: killed off in terrible ways) when appropriate.

Comment: 2/2 Bear in mind, in CoD 2nd Ed, Conservation of Merits means that even if, as the game progresses, the companions become consistently mechanically beneficial, and thus must be "bought onto the sheet", they can still be done in without the player getting short-changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about red-shirts. I will probably control them and get them killed as a sign that dangers are real.